# Assembly: Program outputs special ASCII characters

Tags: assembly, masm

I need help in writing a program in MASM that ask users for input and outputs ASCII special characters. For example, if the user writes:

```
hello \01 i missed you \03.
```

It would output it as:

```
hello ☺ i missed you ♥.
```

I know that for printing a smiley face I can use the following code:

```
MOV AH, 6
MOV DL, 1; print ☺
INT 21H
```

But I don't know how to do it automatically when a user inputs `\01`. Any assistance will be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are reading the input by DOS service, then `"\01"` is encoded as three bytes: 92, 48, 49 (check ASCII table if you don't understand where those values come from).

So what you need is to replace those three bytes in the string with single byte of value 1, and move the remaining part of string two bytes "left" to compact it (ie. string replacement).

Now to know which part of string should be replaced with what you have to write some kind of parser, which will detect the `'\'` character, read some digits/chars after it (you have to define what is correct syntax, like if it is always two characters after `\` forming hexadecimal byte value, ie. `"\4A"` would turn into `J`, or up-to-three-digits 0-9 forming decimal value, ie. `"\122"` would turn into `z`), convert those digits/chars into byte value, and use that byte value as replacement for that parsed part.

Also for "pro" quality solution make sure your parser is robust enough to survive invalid syntax like `\<EOF>`, and to have some reasonable syntax, like `\\01` turning into `\01` without parsing the digits, etc... (see C/C++ string-literal-in-source syntax rules for inspiration).

So start probably first with string replace function, then write the trigger sequence detector, then write parser of value (write them as separate functions if possible + debug/validate them before moving on next subject), and then combine that together into complete solution.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to do that.